# I am trying to create a function that takes in the wall_type ex (1-line horizontal) and randomly places it within a given range on the grid

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, tkinter-canvas

the function wall_gen takes in 2 parameters : "wall_type" and "amount"

"wall_type" determines what type of wall is being generated on the grid
"amount" determines how many times the wall_type is generated

the function then creates an array for both 'wall_type'(wt_list) and the variable(w_list) the wall_type info is being stored into

I use a variable to store the line info so I can delete that line afterwards
(Im using tkinter canvas for drawing lines btw, so the variables look like this "w1=canvas.create_line(0,0,50,0)" )

Anyway the problem Im facing is that the code works if I don't use a while loop, but as soon as I poot a while loop to generate more walls the program crashes

the part of code above is used so to check if the wall generated colides with any of the player positions, if so it loops back, otherwise it just generates the wall and then loops back
|
|
V
" if (player_trail.count(wt_x1+z)>0 or player_trail.count(wt_y1+t)>0 or player_trail.count(wt_x2+z)>0 or player_trail.count(wt_y2+t)>0) "

Please tell me if I made a stupid mistake or smt cus I can't see the problem
Thanks!

```
# @@@@@@ WALL TYPES @@@@@@@@@
wt1=(0,0,  50,0) # 1-line h.
wt2=(0,0,  100,0) # 2-line h.
wt3=(0,0,  150,0) # 3-line h.

wt4=(0,0,  0,50) # 1-line v.
wt5=(0,0,  0,100) # 2-line v.
wt6=(0,0,  0,150) # 3-line v.

wt7=(0,0,  50,50) # 1-1-line d.
wt8=(0,0,  100,100) # 2-2-line d.

wt9=(0,50,  50,0) # fliped 1-1-line d.
wt10=(0,100,  100,0) # fliped 2-2-line d.

wt11=(0,0,  100,50) # 2-1-line hd. 
wt12=(0,0,  50,100) # 2-1-line vd.

wt13=(0,50,  100,0) # fliped 2-1-line hd.
wt14=(0,100,  50,0) # fliped 2-1-line vd.


#@@@@@@ WALL GEN @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
def wall_gen(wall_type,amount):

    global w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6,w7,w8,w9,w10,w11,w12,w13,w14,w15,w16,w17,w18,w19,w20,w21,w22,w23,w24
    global wt1,wt2,wt3,wt4,wt5,wt6,wt7,wt8,wt9,wt10,wt11,wt12,wt13,wt14

    w_list =[0,w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6,w7,w8,w9,w10,w11,w12,w13,w14,w15,w16,w17,w18,w19,w20,w21,w22,w23,w24]
    wt_list=[0,wt1,wt2,wt3,wt4,wt5,wt6,wt7,wt8,wt9,wt10,wt11,wt12,wt13,wt14]


    # seperates the wall_type into its x1,x2,y1,y2 cordinates 
    wt_x1,wt_y1,wt_x2,wt_y2=(wt_list[wall_type])


    
    plusx_list=[200,250,300]
    plusy_list=[200,250,300]

   
    
    wall_number=1
    while wall_number<=amount:
        
        # gets a random value from a 'plusx_list' and 'plusy_list' lists to be added to wall_type x1,x2,y1,y2 cordinates 
        z=random.choice(plusx_list)
        t=random.choice(plusy_list)
        if (player_trail.count(wt_x1+z)>0 or player_trail.count(wt_y1+t)>0 or player_trail.count(wt_x2+z)>0 or player_trail.count(wt_y2+t)>0) : 
            continue
            
        if (player_trail.count(wt_x1+z)<1 and player_trail.count(wt_y1+t)<1 and player_trail.count(wt_x2+z)<1 and player_trail.count(wt_y2+t)<1): 
            (w_list[wall_number])=canvas.create_line(wt_x1+z, wt_y1+t, wt_x2+z, wt_y2+t)
            wall_number+1
            print(wall_number)
```

Comment: Try using tkinters `after(delay, function)` instead of while loop.

Comment: I searched it up and I only found the after(delay, function) being used as timer to dilay the function execution, not sure if its posible to use it inside a function. also I failed to mention the "wall_number" is used to stop the the wall generation after the "wall_number" is greater than the 'amount'.

Comment: `after` can take parameters, `.after(delay, function, *args, **kwd)`. Then just have function calling itself until some value is met. I can't run your code but it seems doable.

Comment: thanks for the help, Ill tinker around with it, if not for this part of code it'll be useful later on